# how to sync data between android & server?

Tags: android, sqlite, synchronization

I want to develop an app in which i will sync data between app & server.as of now i enter some data to app & save it locally when it is saved in sqlite then i send the same data to server.In this way i can view the data even if there is no internet connection.But now issue is user can also update or update the data from server end.So every time i should get the latest data.

1.Should i run a service which check every time number of records on sqlite & server.If there is difference then show latest data.

Please tell the solution.

Comment: could be done using timestamps. Client asks server for new data including the timestamp in the request. Server delivers new data since the transfered timestamp. For Realtime Updates, you could use something like socket.io (or websockets in general). So the server can push updates to the client

Comment: but time can be different for server & local app.?@aschattney

Comment: unix timestamp should be the same, am i wrong?

Comment: If you dont mind relying on a BaaS, then parse.com supports something like this using what they call a Local Datastore

Comment: i have no idea regarding this

Comment: No i don't want to use baas? I heard of sync adapters & gcm which should be used

Comment: If you are looking for real-time sync then https://www.firebase.com/ might be interesting for you.